# Can no longer enter comments on Stack Overflow with IE8, IE9, IE10

Tags: support, comments, internet-explorer

Starting about an hour ago: on Stack Overflow I can no longer enter comments (clicking `add/show 4 more comments` does nothing) and I can no longer get the `Help` menu to display (e.g., get to Meta).

I'm using IE8 on Windows 7 (similar problems have been reported on IE9 and IE10 as well), and no, I am not using Compatibility mode.

- When I click `comment` nothing happens, except the browser page is redisplayed to show the top of the page.
- When I click `Help` in the top bar, nothing happens in Stack Overflow: no menu -- unless I am on my user homepage.
- When I click `StackExchange` in the top bar, instead of the drop-down menu, it takes me to a generic welcome page for StackExchange, which says "**expert answers to your questions**".
- I've tried logging out and back in, and even closing the browser and reopening it.
- I've tried deleting my browser cache.
- I've tried clearing the browser cache and cookies for the StackExchange domain.

Behavior appears to be intermittent. If I go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs# and I reload the page, then the site switcher works momentarily. But if I then go here: [xcscope responds "File does not have expected format"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176462/xscope-unable-to-handle-file-does-not-have-expected-format), even if I reload the page, the site switcher no longer works (likewise `comment`).

Here is an image showing an error with IE10 on SU. The site kicks the browser into compatibility view (mode). I turn off compatibility view. It comes back on again... Then this. (I'm using Chrome to be able to post this now etc.)

[image]

Comment: Clear your browser cache and cookies, log in and try again.  Consider upgrading to a newer browser; Microsoft will stop supporting IE8 in April, and any hope of getting a fix from SE will evaporate then.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in the console? Are you seeing any network errors (ie. resources that are not loading)?

Comment: Look in the developer tools - F12 takes you there. You may need to reload the page to see anything recorded.

Comment: IE8 isn't officially supported anyway, so the chances of getting a fix may already be slim: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: IE8 is the last version that supports Windows XP. I would not be surprised if this is the case for OP.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante - with IE 8, we will ensure functionality is preserved. We don't care too much about some visual glitches, however, so long as they don't interfere with functionality.

Comment: I have tried IE 11 in IE 8 mode, but couldn't reproduce. Have you been able to take a look at the developer tools and see if you see any JavaScript errors or network errors?

Comment: @Oded: That's all I would ask for. And as you can see, somehow `comment` is working again.

Comment: What about the help and Stack Exchange site switcher?

Comment: `comment` is now working for me again here (Meta) but not yet on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Oded: And the StackExchange site switcher is also working again. I did not see where to look (with F12) for JavaScript & network errors. I did use F12 to clear the cache and SE cookies.

Comment: @Oded: I take that back about the site switcher. It worked once, but now it's back to showing the "expert answers to your questions" page.

Comment: I don't have IE 8 on this machine and IE 11 has changed the developer tools quite a bit, but for JavaScript errors, you should be able to see a Script tab and a console button that should show any warnings and errors.

Comment: @Oded: No, sorry; the switcher is working again. Guess I just needed to reload the page at SO. (I thought I had done that.)

Comment: So... all back to normal?

Comment: @Oded: No, I still cannot use `comment` or the site switcher on SO. 

`Script > Console` shows only this text: `LOG: isElectionPrimary: false`.

Comment: No yellow/red triangles/circles anywhere?

Comment: @Oded: No. the console is empty except for `LOG: isElectionPrimary: false`.

Comment: @nhahtdh latest Chrome and Firefox still install fine on XP though.

Comment: I am getting the exact same problem this morning on IE9.

Comment: See my update. SE, SO etc. are ***totally unusable for IE10*** - for me at least. Does anyone see something different for IE10? (I'm posting this from Google Chrome.) Hard to believe that SE does not seem to be taking this breakage very seriously.

Comment: Ran across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011653/internet-explorer-automatically-switches-to-compatibility-mode-ie9-and-ie10) - don't know if it has any relevance to your situation, but... Might be worth investigating (check to see if you have any crusty old fonts named Helvetica installed).

Comment: @Shog9: I see, but I don't quite understand what I should do. I do have Helvetica on my laptop, and it is needed for my work, AFAIK. The post you cite seems to say that it is the use of Helvetica in CSS that leads to the problem. Does the SE CSS use Helvetica?

Comment: It's listed in the CSS for... Not Windows systems, IIRC. Delete / move it somewhere temporary & see if you're able to get out of Compat mode.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't know how or where to do that. Where is the "CSS for... Not Windows system", for instance?

Comment: @Shog: F12 on SE shows me this in the console window: **SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf' 
full.en.js, line 168 character 184**. Does that help at all?

Comment: Are you still in compatibility mode, @Drew?

Comment: All SE, SO etc sites automatically kick IE10 into compatibility view. If I then turn it off, it comes right back on again. I've posted an image of the error from SU, above. (Using Chrome to do this, of course, though it is IE where the problems occur.)

Comment: @Shog: The [page](http://bobbyjoneswebdesign.blogspot.com/2011/12/internet-explorer-9-type-1-font-bug.html) you pointed to says that this is a problem with IE9 (and apparently IE10 too). And they say that there is a solution for web sites (in fact there are 4 solutions - au choix). The "best solution" is for the site not to use the problematic Type 1 fonts. Can't SE fix that, so users do not need to each, individually, uninstall their Type 1 fonts?

Comment: I have no idea if that's even relevant here, Drew - can you see if removing the font has any effect on the symptoms you're observing?

Comment: @Shog9 there are several validation errors for the HTML, see [this](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F224118%2Fcan-no-longer-enter-comments-on-stack-overflow-with-ie8&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Maybe this is throwing IE10 into compatibility mode? I'm pretty sure those errors wasn't always there. (not the "Bad value og:xxxx for attribute name on element meta", those aren't relevant)

Comment: @Drew Have you tried running a sandbox yourself? I haven't encountered any issues using a VM with IE 10 (from http://modern.ie/) and I'm also not seeing compatibility mode kicking in: http://i.imgur.com/2cEM8V5.png

Comment: @Drew and here's a comment posted from IE8 in Windows XP. I had a little trouble logging in because the search bar is hovering over the login button in the top bar, but I didn't have any other problems to post this comment. http://i.imgur.com/hKhbtCQ.png

Comment: CC @Shog9 no-repro for me.

Comment: I have tried reproducing with IE 8 on Windows 7 - no repro.

Comment: @Drew - can you confirm whether this is still happening? I have one report that the problem went away.

Comment: I'm placing this comment via IE10 on Win 8, no repo.

Comment: @Shog: Yes, I can confirm that everything I described is still happening (with IE10 - I no longer have IE8 ;-)).

Comment: @Shog: I will not be removing the Type 1 fonts from my system - sorry. I absolutely need at least some of them for my work. FWIW, I have these Type 1 fonts: Euro Monospace, Euro Sans, Euro Serif, Helvetica, Helvetica-Narrow, Palatino, Symbol Regular, Times, and ZapfDingbats Regular.  I use Palatino heavily, in particular.

Comment: I'm suggesting you remove the Helvetica fonts *temporarily*, @Drew - if it doesn't fix the problem, then we know that's not what's causing it. If it does, then there's a chance we can fix that on our end. I rather doubt that's the problem here, but it's something you could test quickly to help narrow it down. FWIW, we don't reference Palatino anywhere that would matter for this.

Comment: @Shog: Yes, I plan to try that. I'm waiting for confirmation at work that we do not really need Helvetica. I know that we need Palatino, but I can see that Helvetica is used in the CSS of various web sites (not just SE), and I have not yet noticed that wrt Palatino. With luck I can remove Helvetica and that will fix the problem.

Comment: Works fine here (IE11, Win8.1)

Comment: @Oded - I had problems for several hours yesterday, just as described. Without making any changes, they seem to have mostly disappeared. Very strange. IE8 on Windows 7. (The site kicks into compatibility mode every time I post a comment, but I seem to be able to turn it off.)

Comment: @JDB - we haven't changed any related functionality on our end - yours is one of several reports of this "fixing itself". We never got down to the actual underlying issue (assuming it was on our end) - it certainly was not consistent and many IE users didn't seem to experience it at all.

Comment: @Oded - Yeah, it's a weird problem. But then again, it's IE8. Oh how I *hate* this browser.

Comment: @Oded (and JDB): Yes, in IE8 you could turn Compatibility mode off after it came on automatically (which it did after entering comments - nothing new about that)  and it stayed off (until you created another comment). 

In IE10 if you turn it off it comes right back on again.  And in IE10 you cannot even get the comment box - cannot create the comment (that was also true of IE8, but not before yesterday).

Comment: @Shog et al: I have upgraded from IE10 to IE11. The problems I had with SE sites have disappeared, and I was able to keep all of the Type 1 fonts I have (and need). Thanks for all the help, esp. Shog's pointing me to the Bobby Jones article about the Helvetica problem. I guess this issue remains open for IE8 and IE10, but at least I am a happy camper once more. ;-) I have been informed that some other, non-SE sites are problematic wrt IE11, but so far things are much better than with IE10. Thx again.

Answer (score 14):

First, [we cannot support IE 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need). If it works, great - if it doesn't, **upgrade:** at this point, you're three versions behind current, and likely running into problems elsewhere too.

Second, make *double-certain* you're not dropping into "IE7 compatibility mode" when this occurs. I'm not accusing you of turning it on - I'm suggesting IE is turning it on in response to *something* on *some pages*. If you can identify what this is, it might be possible to fix. The vast majority of the problems we run into with IE are caused by compatibility mode - everyone thinks they have it turned off, somehow it turns itself on. [Instructions for disabling it can be found here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view).

Third, just wait. At least [a few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224147/links-to-add-comment-add-show-more-view-message-box-not-working) [people](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/having-trouble-writing-comments-today) who originally encountered this problem have now seen it go away - with no changes on our end *or* theirs. Don't really have a good explanation for this, but hey - worth a shot.

Comment: What proportion of site users are still on IE8?

Comment: (Great, I was able to add a comment here.) The very page you point to as expressing the SE policy on browser support says the ***opposite*** of the text you used for that link ("*we cannot support IE8*"). 

That policy page says that you will continue to **support current and previous versions of all browsers that have some reasonable market share**.

Comment: @Drew 4.24% according to [this](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php). Up to the team here, which Shog represents, to decide if it's considered reasonable or not.

Comment: I use IE8 at work (I *have* to... at least we finally upgraded out of Win XP this year). I've been having intermittent problems with commenting and accessing vote counts. Hopefully we'll upgrade to IE9 soon, but with so many of our aging core web applications (third-party vendors) simply not working on newer versions of IE, it's not likely to be soon.

Comment: @JDB Well looks like it is broken on IE9 anyway so that won't help!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Add in the numbers for IE10 and IE9 (and IE11?). And take a look at browser use on *desktops*, which might better represent people at work, including developers: [***58% IE***](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=0&qpcustomd=0). And that includes [***26% IE8, 17% IE9, 0.16% IE10***](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0)

Comment: @Drew I'm not sure how you got those percentages for IE version distribution. If I click that link, I see this: **IE8 21.73%, IE9 8.8%, IE10 8.04%, IE11 12.8%**. In other words, two in five IE users have an SE-compatible IE10 or 11. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/sBEGgql.png). I didn't fiddle with anything, just clicked and looked.

Comment: @Drew well, IE10 is supported so this is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Great. Looking forward to it. Sorry for being the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Shog - poke. Did you notice the last comments from OP claiming it's not working in IE10 as well? Should he start new report?

Comment: Sorry Microsoft still supports Vista for a few years, and IE9 is the limit of what will run on Vista.  Your policy is saying that someone must install custom access software to use Stack Exchange sites, it is just like a shop refusing to let anyone park if they have a car that is over a few years old.

Comment: @Ian That's a terrible metaphor and you know it. Does a shop need to make modifications to their parking lot to let older cars park there?

Comment: Shog, not everyone works at a start-up. Some of us work in IT departments where the tools we use are dictated to us, for better or worse. I can't even get them to install Paint.NET on my machine (a free tool, even for businesses). It's totally up to SE if you want to shut out professionals like me, but telling us to **upgrade** is just adding salt to the wound. *Of course* I want to upgrade, but I *can't*. You're literally better off telling someone in Portugal to learn English.

Comment: @Stijn, No, but they should not make any charges to their parking lots without first checking that it does not stop any cars parking there that are allready able to do so.

Comment: No one's trying to shut you out, @JDB - with the possible exception of your own IT dept. Look, I'm more than familiar with working for organizations where you have to break the rules just to get your job done, but that's neither here nor there. 'Fact is, you're likely prevented from upgrading for *the same reason:* your team isn't able to support another browser version. When I say it's not feasible to maintain support for increasingly-obscure browsers, it has nothing to do with shutting anyone out - it's purely an observation of the impracticality of trying to do otherwise.

Comment: I totally understand and I'm not upset about it. I meant "shut out professionals like me *who are stuck using ancient browsers due to corporate policy*". (I figured the last bit was implied.) But you *are* implicitly making the decision to shut out professionals in my situation by not, at least, keeping existing features functional. (As others have said, what improvements were introduced that made it worth breaking IE8 funcationality?) But here's the point: it's a decision *you* are making - telling *us* to upgrade (when you know many can't) is not productive or helpful to the conversation.

Comment: I'm feeling just a tad inspired to return to IE as my primary browser after 8 years.

Comment: @JDB: as has been noted here several times, *we didn't change anything that should've affected this.* We've actually been rather careful to *avoid* functionality we know doesn't exist in older versions of IE - and yet, it broke yesterday for a handful of people. So what can we do about that? If I was still working in Corporate IT, supporting all of two versions of one browser, I'd have VMs set up with every permutation of Windows, IE and recent patches along with the standard LOB apps - but of course that's not feasible to do for the entire Internet audience.

Comment: I have worked in several web shops and completely understand. It's the attitude, which is unfortunately common: *You're still using **that** ancient technology? Why don't you just **upgrade**?* I see it all the time on SO, and it's dissapointing to see from the SE team as well. Those kinds of comments are simply not constructive. You're telling me something I already know and can't do anything about. Just tell me you can't devote resources toward maintaining backwards compatibility with browsers that are steadily losing market share, but please don't patronize me by telling me to **upgrade**.

Comment: Patronizing you would be telling you that you're not gonna have problems, @JDB. You're stuck in a bad situation - I recognize that, I can *empathize* with that... But *lying to you* isn't gonna fix it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been using IE8 on a Windows 7 laptop all week at work, and have not had any issues with the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - may $deity have mercy on your (brown) soul. IE8 all week?

Comment: Hey, @Oded - for the year and a half *before* this week, it was IE8 on *Windows XP*.  This is an "upgrade!"

Comment: @jadarnel27 - OK. May $deity have no mercy on your employer ;) not brown, not brown at all.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to comment on the answer to say "Me, too!" but on **IE9**, but because I was having the same problem (can't enter comments) I had to do it with an answer.  SE then took my short answer and converted it to a comment, so great.

But I wanted to say that for some reason I cannot even log in using Stack Exchange on FireFox 26.0.

I am entering this answer via Chrome because I can't put in comments using IE9 (nor can I click on up/downvotes to see the breakdown).

I cannot upgrade to IE10 because my employer's policy -- we're supposed to upgrade no higher than ie9, and our internal apps must support IE6 - 9.

Comment: IE6? Ouch... I hope you get paid extra for that.

Comment: Nope. :-)  It happens that IE6 is almost gone away here.  But it's a state gov't intranet with 40K users, so there are a few holdout agencies that apparently think they are still in the buggywhip manufacturing business.

Answer (score 10):

I have to agree with @Cyberharbalist. My employer dictates what version of IE I use and I have to have it in compatibility mode due to some internal applications I must use. If this change is not reversed, I will have to consider leaving SO as I cannot upgrade my work system for valid work reasons. This was a shortsighted change that doesn't reflect how non-IT based companies work. Lots of us work in other business domains.

And what is with the unreadable CAPTCHA stuff today? You need to test that with people who have bifocals for goodness sakes.

Edited to answer comment. No of course they do not let us install any old software we want. The business world doesn't work that way even if it does in IT only shops.

What bothers me most about this change is that all the stuff that broke is not new, it is stuff I have been able to do all along. Why gratuitously break it without any new functionality? What kind of poor project management is that? We try not to break stuff that works unless we have to make a change. Why aren't you doing the same? And please remember that on the other SO sites, eventually the majority of users may not be IT people. Non-IT people avoid upgrading as much as possible. What you are doing is throwing away contributors for what seems to be no valid reason except you only want to support the newest.

Comment: Don't they let you install Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: @Stijn : I happen to be a dev and have privileges of installing whatever darned software I want to install (they trust us not to be stupid - a dubious proposition I will admit). So for the sake of making sure my stuff works everywhere, I have every browser from IE to Opera and even Sleipnir.  Most of the non-dev people in my organization do not have this privilege, and don't have admin authority on their own machines.

Comment: @HLGEM: It actually takes a significant amount of resources to support older versions of browsers, and comes with significant loss of ability to provide the best features for people keeping up with versions. This isn't a matter of just wanting to support the newest.

Comment: "Why gratuitously break it without any new functionality" - we didn't. Or at least, not intentionally. And non of us who tried are able to reproduce the breakage either - it is clear some people are having problems (IE 8/9/10), but others, using the same browsers, are not. I would love to get down to the bottom of this and get it sorted out for everyone. //cc @Drew