# Links to 'Add Comment', 'Add/Show more', View Message Box not working

Tags: support, stack-overflow, internet-explorer

**Update # 2:**  Is it me? (Yes, it is. I just fired up my laptop and I don't have this issue, so it's something new with my desktop!) Running Vista, IE9, no software changes since a couple of Microsoft .Net security updates three days ago - problem started TODAY -- on StackOverflow.com site.
So far I have done the following - without helping:

1. Reset IE settings
2. Rebooted
3. Backed out the two Microsoft security updates to .Net (from 3/1)
4. Cleared cookies, temp internet files, etc.
5. Disabled all IE Add-On's
6. Uninstalled IE9, reinstalled (errors - left me with IE7); updates; then could install IE9
7. Reboots; same problems exist; research switch to Chrome / Firefox

**Then as magically as they appeared, with no changes by me, the gremlins moved on... Out of the clear blue, on 3/5 ~ 10:00AM the problems disappeared.**

A. When I click on 'Add Comment' link, it just jumps to the top of the screen and unable to enter info. See last 'Add Comment' link at the bottom of the following screen:
[MS ACCESS VBA: Me.Dirty = False OnTimer Event Reverts Edited Textbox Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106455/ms-access-vba-me-dirty-false-ontimer-event-reverts-edited-textbox-data/22106546?noredirect=1#comment33659366_22106546)

B. Another issue is if I click on link "Add / show 6 more comments" on the following link, it also justs jumps to the top of the page.
[Microsoft Access 2013 Form Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098613/microsoft-access-2013-form-objects?noredirect=1#)

C. If I click on 'Recent Inbox Messages', the first time I see the list, second time I get no response.

Unable to respond using desktop, but laptop works!!  Thanks!

Comment: I think it just fixed itself... It happened to me, I refreshed the page a few times... maybe it cleared the cache and fixed itself. You're not alone, though... but now it's working!